# "Over quota" when using GCS json-api from App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am using Go on App Engine.  In most cases, I use [the file api](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/appengine-go/appengine/file) to access GCS, which works great, except that [deletes don't work](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10932) so to delete files I use the JSON-API (specifically, the [google-go-api-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/)).  To authenticate, I use [app engine service accounts](https://code.google.com/p/goauth2/source/browse/#hg/appengine/serviceaccount).  We are sometimes seeing an error come back of "Over quota:" with nothing after the colon.  Since we are a paid app, what quota could this be?  Is there a burst limit (e.g. no more than X requests in a single minute)?  Is there any places where any such applicable quotas are documented?

Comment: Hi Ian, that's an interesting problem. Could you please an email to gs-team@google.com with more information about the project, bucket, and operations you are attempting?

Comment: Hi Brandon - I think someone1 has got it.  After looking back at my code, I realized that our function can ALSO return an error if serviceaccount.NewClient fails.  So I bet that is where the Over Quota error is coming from.  We have also bumped into that situation in other cases but I totally failed to realize that it was the same problem.  Sorry for the false alarm!  p.s. would you mind nudging someone inside Google regarding the issue linked below?  Its the root cause of this problem and it makes accessing GCS from appengine rather difficult.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caching mechanism is broken for goauth2 and serviceaccount tokens. You can see the issue I created here for more detail: https://code.google.com/p/goauth2/issues/detail?id=28

I came across a "over quota" issue myself when requesting more than 60 service accounts a minute. I opened a ticket with AppEngine support (I pay for the silver package) and got this undocumented information out of them.

You can apply the patch yourself in your $GOPATH/src/code.google.com/p/goauth2/appengine/serviceaccount/cache.go file. This fixed the issue you described for my team.

Answer (score 0):

Even i had found same problem and found two reasons:-
1.Daily budget
2.Logs retention

Solution:
 for problem 1 increase the daily budget
 for problem 2 increase the retention from 1 to higher GB
![enter image description here][1]

Comment: You had deleted the image