# Strange "Over quota: " error with no further diagnostics

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm running a parallel job to copy data from Heroku into Google Cloud Storage and eventually into Bigquery. The way I'm doing it right now is split the job of querying IDs in the range [61500000, 62000000) into say 40 taskqueue tasks, and inside each task handler is responsible for the subrange say [
61500000, 61512500). Inside each taskqueue task handler, it spawns 3 goroutines to query our Heroku API parallely, and an additional goroutine doing an Insert to Google Cloud Storage. The way the 3 HTTP API input goroutines pump data to the GCS insert goroutine is through io.Pipe().

However, for some reason I can't get this to work except for toy workloads. Virtually every time there will be some shards failing with error:

"Post https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1beta2/b/ethereal-fort-637.appspot.com/o?alt=json&uploadType=multipart: Over quota: "

returned from the storage.ObjectsInsertCall.Do().

I checked everywhere for possible places where we hit the quota for billed apps:
* urlfetch total limits developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#UrlFetch
* instance memory developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/modules/#Go_Instance_scaling_and_class
but still couldn't find the cause.
Below I explain why I ruled out the above possibilities:

- urlfetch total limits
  urlfetch is used in the 3 goroutines to query our API server for JSON data. These 3 goroutines then process the data and send them to the GCS goroutine through io.Pipe(). The code looks something like

  cl := urlfetch.Client(c)
  resp, err := cl.Get("pic-collage.com/...")
  if err != nil {
    if appengine.IsOverQuota(err) {
      c.Errorf("collageJSONByID over quota: %v", err)
    }
    return err
  }

However, while we see numerous "POST www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1beta2...: Over quota: " errors, we never ever see the logs "collageJSONByID ..." related to urlfetches to our Heroku server.

- instance memory
  We are using the B1 instance for our jobs which has 128MB of RAM. Throughout our runs, we see from our appengine console our memory usage is constantly well below 30MB for each and every instance.

I also applied the fix for the caching inside serviceaccounts described in ["Over quota" when using GCS json-api from App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919834/over-quota-when-using-gcs-json-api-from-app-engine) , but the problem persists.

I wonder is it possible for us to get more information about the specific App Engine quota we are exceeding? Or perhaps there are other hidden quotas for Google Cloud Storage that are not mentioned in the docs ?

Comment: Sometimes your GOPATH package might be up-to-date but not your GOROOT packages, so you need to manually clear them. IIRC, there was a bug when you pulled a package in Go 1.2 but pulled an update using Go 1.3 locally. Additionally, you should probably update your libs so that they point to the v1 JSON API endpoint and not the beta: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gs-announce/xJ0f0fsIS_8

Answer (score 0):

The `Over quota:` message can happen when you've reached your daily billing limit.  If you've enabled billing for your application, make sure the daily budget is high enough to cover your usage.